# how subtraction on sql group by statement

Tags: mysql, group-by

i have order_success table and add_purchess table.

order_sucess table...

```
id prod_id qantity
1    2       20
2    4       10
3    4       5
```

now add_purches here..

```
id prod_id qantity
1    2       100
2    4       200
3    4       50
```

now i want to select sum(qantity) as suc_qantity from order_success  group by prod_id.

and substract  from

```
select sum(qantity) as pur_qantity from add_purches  group by prod_id.
```

like this result

```
prod_id  qantity
  2         80
  4         235
```

**please anyone can help me??**

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
SELECT ap.prod_id, SUM(coalesce(ap.quantity, 0)) - SUM(or.quantity) as quantity
FROM add_purchases ap LEFT JOIN order_sucess or
ON ap.prod_id = or.prod_id
GROUP BY ap.prod_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You just add sub query in select in your query

```
select 
    prod_id,
    sum(qantity) as pur_qantity, 
    (select sum(qantity) from order_sucess where order_sucess.prod_id = add_purches.prod_id) success_qantity

from add_purches 
group by prod_id
```